# Ubuntu 22.04, delayed boot due to "r8152" NIC-driver problem?

Tags: boot, 22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04.03 in a VMWare machine - just recently it began having a problem to boot in a timely manner.
Approximately 40 seconds is spent on probing for a nonexistant(!?) "device descriptor". After the delay everything seems to get up and running.

Is there a way to avoid this, a remedy?

I assume it is the "NIC"[1] a USB-dongle-NIC, "Dell FM76N, Made in China"  (https://www.google.com/search?q=Dell+FM76N)

[1] one of the last lines below is about "eth0" changing name, there are no other NIC:s, NAT, NET enabled/connected, this NIC is using a separate network which is for LAB-work.

---

```
$ cd /var/log
$ sudo grep -n r8152 --color=always *.log
auth.log:163:Oct  5 13:00:50 u20 sudo:    hannu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/grep -n r8152 alternatives.log apport.log auth.log bootstrap.log dpkg.log fontconfig.log gpu-manager.log kern.log ubuntu-advantage-license-check.log ubuntu-advantage.log ubuntu-advantage-timer.log vmware-network.1.log vmware-network.2.log vmware-network.3.log vmware-network.4.log vmware-network.5.log vmware-network.6.log vmware-network.7.log vmware-network.8.log vmware-network.9.log vmware-network.log vmware-vmsvc-root.1.log vmware-vmsvc-root.2.log vmware-vmsvc-root.3.log vmware-vmsvc-root.log vmware-vmtoolsd-root.log
auth.log:166:Oct  5 13:01:01 u20 sudo:    hannu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/grep -n r8152 --color=always alternatives.log apport.log auth.log bootstrap.log dpkg.log fontconfig.log gpu-manager.log kern.log ubuntu-advantage-license-check.log ubuntu-advantage.log ubuntu-advantage-timer.log vmware-network.1.log vmware-network.2.log vmware-network.3.log vmware-network.4.log vmware-network.5.log vmware-network.6.log vmware-network.7.log vmware-network.8.log vmware-network.9.log vmware-network.log vmware-vmsvc-root.1.log vmware-vmsvc-root.2.log vmware-vmsvc-root.3.log vmware-vmsvc-root.log vmware-vmtoolsd-root.log
auth.log:169:Oct  5 13:01:05 u20 sudo:    hannu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/grep -n r8152 --color=always alternatives.log apport.log auth.log bootstrap.log dpkg.log fontconfig.log gpu-manager.log kern.log ubuntu-advantage-license-check.log ubuntu-advantage.log ubuntu-advantage-timer.log vmware-network.1.log vmware-network.2.log vmware-network.3.log vmware-network.4.log vmware-network.5.log vmware-network.6.log vmware-network.7.log vmware-network.8.log vmware-network.9.log vmware-network.log vmware-vmsvc-root.1.log vmware-vmsvc-root.2.log vmware-vmsvc-root.3.log vmware-vmsvc-root.log vmware-vmtoolsd-root.log
auth.log:172:Oct  5 13:01:15 u20 sudo:    hannu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/grep -n r8152 --color=always alternatives.log apport.log auth.log bootstrap.log dpkg.log fontconfig.log gpu-manager.log kern.log ubuntu-advantage-license-check.log ubuntu-advantage.log ubuntu-advantage-timer.log vmware-network.1.log vmware-network.2.log vmware-network.3.log vmware-network.4.log vmware-network.5.log vmware-network.6.log vmware-network.7.log vmware-network.8.log vmware-network.9.log vmware-network.log vmware-vmsvc-root.1.log vmware-vmsvc-root.2.log vmware-vmsvc-root.3.log vmware-vmsvc-root.log vmware-vmtoolsd-root.log
kern.log:2:Oct  4 09:05:39 u20 kernel: [   50.409046] r8152 3-2:1.0 enx9cebe8178b61: carrier on
kern.log:1632:Oct  4 09:19:05 u20 kernel: [    2.698977] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
kern.log:1642:Oct  4 09:19:05 u20 kernel: [   45.527443] r8152 3-2:1.0: load rtl8153a-3 v2 02/07/20 successfully
kern.log:1643:Oct  4 09:19:05 u20 kernel: [   45.567497] r8152 3-2:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13
kern.log:1644:Oct  4 09:19:05 u20 kernel: [   45.580584] r8152 3-2:1.0 enx9cebe8178b61: renamed from eth0
kern.log:1709:Oct  4 09:19:06 u20 kernel: [   48.237562] r8152 3-2:1.0 enx9cebe8178b61: carrier on
kern.log:4880:Oct  5 12:27:55 u20 kernel: [    6.279056] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
kern.log:4892:Oct  5 12:27:55 u20 kernel: [   49.105507] r8152 3-2:1.0: load rtl8153a-3 v2 02/07/20 successfully
kern.log:4893:Oct  5 12:27:55 u20 kernel: [   49.140952] r8152 3-2:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13
kern.log:4894:Oct  5 12:27:55 u20 kernel: [   49.153858] r8152 3-2:1.0 enx9cebe8178b61: renamed from eth0
kern.log:4959:Oct  5 12:27:55 u20 kernel: [   51.657004] r8152 3-2:1.0 enx9cebe8178b61: carrier on
kern.log:6527:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [    2.760584] usbcore: registered new device driver r8152-cfgselector
kern.log:6532:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [    3.020399] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
kern.log:6533:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [    8.478921] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
kern.log:6534:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [   24.091107] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
kern.log:6535:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [   24.438855] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
kern.log:6536:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [   29.723088] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
kern.log:6537:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [   45.339100] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
kern.log:6538:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [   45.687010] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
kern.log:6539:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [   45.760836] r8152 3-2:1.0: load rtl8153a-3 v2 02/07/20 successfully
kern.log:6540:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [   45.792953] r8152 3-2:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13
kern.log:6541:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [   45.793222] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
kern.log:6544:Oct  5 12:45:51 u20 kernel: [   45.818148] r8152 3-2:1.0 enx9cebe8178b61: renamed from eth0
kern.log:6602:Oct  5 12:45:52 u20 kernel: [   48.351570] r8152 3-2:1.0 enx9cebe8178b61: carrier on
kern.log:8151:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [    2.715223] usbcore: registered new device driver r8152-cfgselector
kern.log:8157:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [    2.978342] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
kern.log:8158:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [    8.242288] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
kern.log:8159:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [   23.858439] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
kern.log:8160:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [   24.211021] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
kern.log:8161:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [   29.490460] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
kern.log:8162:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [   45.106555] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
kern.log:8163:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [   45.455089] r8152-cfgselector 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
kern.log:8164:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [   45.544299] r8152 3-2:1.0: load rtl8153a-3 v2 02/07/20 successfully
kern.log:8165:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [   45.584403] r8152 3-2:1.0 eth0: v1.12.13
kern.log:8166:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [   45.584478] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
kern.log:8169:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [   45.610291] r8152 3-2:1.0 enx9cebe8178b61: renamed from eth0
kern.log:8227:Oct  5 12:56:02 u20 kernel: [   48.052503] r8152 3-2:1.0 enx9cebe8178b61: carrier on
```

Comment: Similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488178/r8169-ethernet-driver-stop-working-in-lubuntu-22-04 - might it be related?